# VS 2015 Xamarin: Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android app using Xamarin.

Visual Studio shows this warning, and I don't know what it means. I've followed the instructions but I can't seem to find the `temp\\file`

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail Description
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   daijoubu-app        1   Active  To see what caused the issue, please try below.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt
3. Set environment variable “TraceDesignTime” to true (set TraceDesignTime=true)
4. Delete .vs directory/.suo file
5. Restart VS from the command prompt you set the environment varaible (devenv)
6. Open the solution
7. Check 'C:\Users\Noli\AppData\Local\Temp\\daijoubu-app_*.designtime.log' and look for the failed tasks (FAILED)
```

The full source is available on [github](https://github.com/nolivaldeziii/daijoubu-app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just followed the instructions but it did not eradicate the warning,
although I ignored it, it does not appear now.

1. When rebuilding the project, I noticed it takes a long time because it downloads a zipfile on your `%userprofile%/AppData/Local/Xamarin/zips/*`

-Make sure to not interrupt the build because it will stop downloading and will cause an invalid zip later on, thus reproducing this issue?

2. Another hypothesis is that I included a component(referenced a dll) and then deleted it, and then re-added it. (as I'm having trouble with intellisense)

Comment: do you remember what was the name of the dll you referenced? Because personally (in my two computers) i have problems with mono's `System.ObjectModel.dll`. Somehow VS2015 does not recognize it and appears with a yellowish icon under the droid project references.

Comment: @CodeArtist after you can clean your solution warning disappears. You can also remove `System.ObjectModel` from your references and again add it again. Clean and build warning disappears.

Comment: In my case I updated my Xamarin Forms to latest stable version to get rid of  the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's not an 'Error' it's a warning.

Here's what actually happens:

- Visual studio/xamarin check for required sdkbuild tools for your project
- If you have it already in your SDK then no problem
- If not, your project will show above warning in most of project cases.

How to fix this :

- Clean your solution
- Rebuild it (at this stage visual studio will automatically try to download zips)
- If you get Rebuild canceled error, then close visual studio and start again
- At this stage it will definitely download required zips.
- Again Clean -> Rebuild -> Build -> Close the visual studio and open it again

Or Simplest alternative is

Download all SDKBuild tools available.

Your warning will be gone.

Let me know if it works, coz its worked for me several times.

Answer (score 1):

I too had both Intellisense and compilation issues.

On my Xamarin Forms and Android project, what worked for me is checking out the Resource.Designer.cs file in my Android project, quitting Visual Studio, and then re-opening it.

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "checking out the Resource.Designer.cs file"? I don't understand what you did there... Did you just open it? Did you reset the file via Git? I am having the same issues and it's driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1):

I had this error also. The error was totally my fault, I was adding some strings to my `strings.xml` file and accidentally left an empty item in there

```
<string name=""></string>
```

This broke the R.java file in a really bad way, as the string/resource didn't have a name/id this is how it was created within R.java.

```
public static final int =0x7f080060;
```

As you can see it's missing its identifier. The moral of the story is: check all of your XML for any errors.

Comment: This error happens with a brand new blank Xamarin app.  Not really sure what Java or strings.xml files you are talking about, since those doesn't exist here.  Are you sure you're replying to the right question?

Comment: your comment makes no sense. I'm pretty sure that by default a strings.xml file is always generated for you, Resources -> values -> strings.xml. I was just posting some advice as if you have any xml errors it can really screw with the xamarain/android build process.

Comment: In a new Xamarin.Forms project there is no file in the `Droid` Project (or the solution) named `strings.xml` -- there *is* a file there named `styles.xml` at that location, is that what you mean? -- or maybe it's been changed? -- Anyway, right now the OP's issue happens with a brand new `File->New->Project->Blank Xaml App (Xamarin.Forms.Portable)` project -- it's definitely not caused by any manual editing that the end user has done, since nothing has been edited yet.

Answer (score 0):

i had got this warning for 5 days. i applied this suggestion and problem is end.

to install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.[BLABLA]'

unzipping has failed:
Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip
in the C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\content directory

Reason: File C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip is not a ZIP archive

1) Downloading the zip and installing it didn't solve my issues, I got fewer errors, but in general, the messages stayed the same, Please install package [BLABLA], Unzipping failed,...

2) Next I took a look at the zip file they mention in C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips and indeed, 96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip was corrupt. I deleted this zip, did build my project again, and after the build process (this takes a while, leave it 'building': you see your zip reappear and growing to 135MB) all the previous warnings/errors were gone!

Answer (score 0):

- Save and close your project.
- Go to your path folder.
- Move the `bin` and `obj` folders from the Android folder to another
  location.
- Run the project again.

Moving these folders means deleting them and backing them up just in case!

I solved it this way. I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

I also had this annoying experience, in App2.Droid
"Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled."
... but I seem to have fixed it on my pc.

At certain times when rebuilding my project I also had other errors than the usual ones, telling me

```
to install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.[BLABLA]'

unzipping has failed:
Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip
in the C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\content directory

Reason: File C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip is not a ZIP archive
```

1) **Downloading the zip and installing it didn't solve my issues**, I got fewer errors, but in general, the messages stayed the same, Please install package [BLABLA], Unzipping failed,...

2) Next I took a look at the zip file they mention in C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips and indeed, 96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip was corrupt.
**I deleted this zip, did build my project again, and after the build process (this takes a while, leave it 'building': you see your zip reappear and growing to 135MB) all the previous warnings/errors were gone!**

It seems manually putting the unzipped files in place didn't work because VS was still trying to unzip the corrupt zip file.
This zip file is unzipped after the first build of the droid project. I remember initially I manually stopped the building of the droid project several times because it was extremely slow and it appeared to hang: probably the first build action tried to download the zip file and unzip it,
canceling (I might have even shot down VS one time) that build that took like forever (I had a terribly slow internet connection that evening) corrupted the zip.

Note:

- in C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips there are several zip files, my error did tell me the name of the right one.
- in C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design I had several 23.X folders, one with content in its 'content' subdir, and one without: the 23.0.1.3 one, as specified in the error texts.

Edit: basically [what @trycatch answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659653), his first option is confirmed ;)