# fresh install vs2015 enterprise update 2 when I try to create new project get error

Tags: xamarin.android

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   testOne.Droid       1   Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'testOne, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?   testOne.Droid

Comment: Have you tried anything to resolve this or was SO your first stop after getting the error?  If you have already tried something to resolve the error please include that detail.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried repairing install then followed some additional directions found on msdn checking if xamarin needed to be updated through tools options on vs2015.  Searched all over the net for answers found a couple questions that were close but they had no answers.  I have no experience with xamarin or android development my experience is with vb.net and asp.net.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Community 2015 Xamarin: Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640315/vs-community-2015-xamarin-warningide0006error-encountered-while-loading-the-p)