# Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail Description
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   HelloWorld      1   Active  To see what caused the issue, please try below.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt
3. Set environment variable “TraceDesignTime” to true (set TraceDesignTime=true)
4. Delete .vs directory/.suo file
5. Restart VS from the command prompt you set the environment varaible (devenv)
6. Open the solution
7. Check 'C:\Users\nitesh dandekar\AppData\Local\Temp\HelloWorld_*.designtime.log' and look for the failed tasks (FAILED)

Comment: hello.is this a question or solution that helped you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Community 2015 Xamarin: Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640315/vs-community-2015-xamarin-warningide0006error-encountered-while-loading-the-p)

Comment: Check following ans : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649002/8123187)

Answer (score 1):

In effect, this error appears when the virtual device is down or when it is not functioning correctly. Try fixing this by creating a new virtual device within AVD Manager and starting it - then you will have deployed the project.

Answer (score 0):

When this error happened to me, the virtual device was launched by Visual Studio. So, once it was launched and the error was thrown by the compiler, what I did was to re-run the project (android in my case) in Visual Studio without closing the virtual device. This time the compilation/execution was ok and the project was shown in the virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue. I disconnect my android device and connect again. Clean and build project again. Then application deployed successfully.