# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin many problems

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with creating, building and deploying (still on Android) Xamarin/Xamarin.Forms projects on Visual Studio Community 2015
Version v14.0.25431.01 Update 3, Xamarin v4.2.0.680.

I can't build sample opened projects like MvvmCross or XAML examples. What I've done:

- Clean and Rebuild
- Update Xamarin extension
- Update Nuget packages with removing dependenties
- Close and reopen VS
- Tools -> Clear MEF Component cache
- List item

The most common:

> IDE0006    Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.

Who know how to solve it?

P.S: Solved by reinstalling Xamarin extension, Android SDK (NDK, emulators, etc.)

[image]

Comment: Some of the errors are because you're building an iOS app without a mac build host online.

Comment: Check solution: [VS Community 2015 Xamarin: Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36659653/3060520)

Comment: @Gusman yes. I know about it, but I want build only on android for first time.

Comment: @user3060520 did not help. I'm creating a new project and get same errors for defaults. Without interference.

Comment: Post the full build log

Comment: @Gusman https://gist.github.com/undershot/15040c447ecf4af3c7ac97387f50512d

Comment: @Gusman and https://gist.github.com/undershot/6433e706d44a47700bacd34b94bcef0e (didn't deployed)

Comment: "========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========" from the build log shows no error at all, so I assume the errors come from Roslyn in the IDE. Try to disable Intellisense errors/warnings from the Error List Window, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx

Comment: But are you sure the app isn't compiling? for me it seems like it's correctly compiled but not deployed. Are you trying to deploy to an emulator or a device? if it's an emulator, do you have it already open?

Comment: @Gusman https://gist.github.com/undershot/cb64f00e4c1df3addfdb150d944c288c - when i deploy

Comment: Did you use a free software? You know what that's mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had a host of problems with Xamarin under VS2015, e.g. locked files, compiler could not find files etc..  They all disappeared when I transferred my solution from a network drive to a local drive.